# How does an airline develop a Safety Management System (SMS) program?

Tags: safety, airline-operations

How does an airline develop an SMS program? Like from the ground up. And who does it involve? Does it involve regulators?
I know the 4 pillars but who does it involve?

Comment: I would start by hiring someone who has one it before.

Comment: How large is your operation ?

Comment: @skipper44 just a typical legacy carrier.

Comment: Start with AC120-92

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good first step is to have your CEO downwards attend an official SMS workshop or class. Not only is it a requirement for implementation, but it gives the necessary orientation for the top brass to understand the system and hence their responsibility and commitment as 'Accountable Manager' etc.

When SMS was first introduced well over a decade ago, ICAO had provided for a phased implementation for States and Operators over a 3(?) year period. Even the best run organisations were 'novices' when it came to this task. More recent documentation showed an 18 month implementation, and the latest documents seem not to provide a timeline. This is probably due to the fact that there is now a huge amount of experience gained worldwide by both regulator and industry. Here's a useful intro video provided by the UK CAA:

The process of setting up SMS for an Airline should ideally have a Safety Manager exclusively attached to the task through the 3 implementation phases. And YES, the Regulator is intimately involved in the process of implementation and after.
Here's some FAQ answered by the UK CAA and below that some FAA guidance on the implementation of the 3 'Levels.

[image: some FAQ answered by the UK CAA]

[image: FAA Implementation Levels]

In case your's is a smaller operation, there's guidance available with most regulators to address the implementation appropriately.

In any case, do check for the latest rules with your regulator.